# CPLEX with anaconda/python academic version

Tags: anaconda, cplex, docplex

i have installed the CPLEX optimization studio (academic version) and currently looking for a way to access it through anaconda/python. Anyone has some insights? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CPLEX ships with a Python API that allows you to access CPLEX from Python. You can find the documentation for the Python API in the online manual [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/help.html).